# Google Earth Engine Classification Collection Mode Frequency for pixel confidence/stability/agreement

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-classification, image-classification, machine-learning

I am trying to obtain the mode and the mode frequency per pixel of different iterations of a Random Forest Classifier (With a fixed number of trees but with different random seeds) with 5 classes (0 to 4). So far, I can easily extract the mode from the collection with  `var GUE_Mode = ee.ImageCollection(MyCollection).mode()` function, but I haven't found a way to add another band to depict the count per pixel of the mode class frequency in the collection, to add a measure of pixel confidence/stability/agreement. Say, if I have 20 different iterations, I would like each pixel in the mode image to have a band depicting how many images depict this pixel classified as the mode class, to add higher confidence to the pixel depicted as that class in 19/20 or 20/20, than to those below this value.
This is the code I have been developing for this purpose, so far without the desired output:

```
// Function to count the frequency of each mode pixel on the collection
var addModeFrequency = function(mode, collection) {
  // Extract the mode class
  var ModeClass = mode.select('LULC');

  // Define a function to count occurrences of mode class in each image
  var countOccurrence = function(image) {
    // Extract the class band from the image
    var ImageClass = image.select('LULC');
    // Count the pixels where mode class matches image class
    var count = ModeClass.eq(ImageClass).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: mode.geometry(),
      scale: 60,
      maxPixels: 1e9
    }).getNumber('LULC');
    // Return the count as an image with same geometry as mode
    return ee.Image.constant(count).rename('counts');
  };

  // Map over the collection to apply countOccurrence function
  var frequency = collection.map(countOccurrence);

  // Merge the frequency images into a single image
  var stabilityMap = ee.ImageCollection(frequency).sum().rename('stability');

  return mode.addBands(stabilityMap);
};

var stabilityMap = addModeFrequency(ee.Image(GUE_mode),ee.ImageCollection(GUE_FC));
print('stabilityMap:', stabilityMap)

// Visualize the stability map
Map.addLayer(stabilityMap.select('stability'), {min: 0, max: 20, palette: ['black', 'white']}, 'Stability Map');
```

Answer (score 0):

I cracked it, here is the code:

```
// Function to count the frequency of each mode pixel on the collection
var addModeFrequency = function(mode, collection) {
  // Define a function to count occurrences of mode class in each image
  var countOccurrence = function(image) {
    // Get the class band from the image
    var classBand = image.select('LULC');
    // Count the pixels where mode class matches image class
    var count = mode.eq(classBand).rename('counts');
    return count;
  };
  // Map over the collection to apply countOccurrence function
  var frequency = collection.map(countOccurrence);
  // Merge the frequency images into a single image
  var sumImage = ee.ImageCollection(frequency).sum().rename('frequency');
  return mode.addBands(sumImage);
};
```